# Python-equivalent of short-form "if" in C++

Tags: python, syntax

Is there a way to write this C/C++ code in Python?
`a = (b == true ? "123" : "456" )`

Comment: It's called a ternary-if, by the way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: ... or "conditional expression"

Answer (score 255, accepted):

```
a = '123' if b else '456'
```

Comment: This ternary operator was introduced in Python 2.5.

Comment: For future reference, here's the Python documentation for the conditional expression: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 25):

While `a = 'foo' if True else 'bar'` is the more modern way of doing the ternary if statement (python 2.5+), a 1-to-1 equivalent of your version might be:

```
a = (b == True and "123" or "456" )
```

... which in python should be shortened to:

```
a = b is True and "123" or "456"
```

... or if you simply want to test the truthfulness of b's value in general...

```
a = b and "123" or "456"
```

`? :` can literally be swapped out for `and or`

Comment: I should note that the and..or approach here can backfire on you if the "123" value were actually an empty string or evaluates to a false value. The if..else is a bit safer.

Answer (score 21):

My cryptic version...

```
a = ['123', '456'][b == True]
```

Comment: That was one of the old approaches before the single-line if statement was possible, right? Kind of like how you can do it with logical: `True and "foo" or "bar"
`

Answer (score -1):

See [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) for more info.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is not an elaborative answer, I dont see it helpful