# How to return keys in original order in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm reading in a file and storing the info in a dict as it reads from top to bottom. I don't want to print out in a wrong order compared to the original file.

Also, a very small question: I remember seeing it somewhere a short form of the if and else statement:

```
if a == 'a':
    a = 'b' ? a = 'c'
```

Do you know the exact form?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  these are both nice questions and a good fit; but because you have two questions, you should ask in two, separate posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).
2. [`a = 'b' if a == 'a' else 'c'`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Python)

Comment: my python is 2.4, is that why it doesn't have OrderedDict module? I have collections but no OrderedDict

Comment: @BPm: Did you read the bit in bold where it says "**See also** [Equivalent OrderedDict recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) that runs on Python 2.4 or later."?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OrderedDict, or you can store the data in a list and index it with a dict, or store it in a dict and save the keys in a list as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `dict` but the short form you're looking for is the [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator)

There's a ternary operator for nearly every language, you can find some example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). However, the one in Python is has not the same syntax has the others like explained in the linked SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are unordered (see [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)).

For your second question, see this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686390/python-equivalent-of-short-form-if-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Second answer first:  [a = 'b' if a == 'a' else 'c'](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions) (known as a ternary expression)

First answer second:  Use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html?#ordereddict-objects), which is available from 2.7 on.

If that's not available to you, you can:

- Store the index as part of each value (a pain)
- Use a previous [Ordered Dictionary implementation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html)