# How to condense if/else into one line in Python?

Tags: python

How might I compress an `if`/`else` statement to one line in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686390/python-equivalent-of-short-form-if-in-c http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: That's the question you wanted to link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator

Comment: another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778400/is-there-control-flow-in-python

Comment: ***This*** is the question I was thinking of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491944/better-way-than-using-if-else-statement-in-python

Comment: Conditional expressions don't cover all cases (or all versions).  Now what?

Answer (score 386):

An example of Python's way of doing "ternary" expressions:

```
i = 5 if a > 7 else 0
```

translates into

```
if a > 7:
   i = 5
else:
   i = 0
```

This actually comes in handy when using list comprehensions, or sometimes in return statements, otherwise I'm not sure it helps that much in creating readable code.

The readability issue was discussed at length in this recent SO question [better way than using if-else statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491944/better-way-than-using-if-else-statement-in-python).

It also contains various other **clever** (and somewhat *obfuscated*) ways to accomplish the same task. It's worth a read just based on those posts.

Comment: How do i use it in the return statement?    `return count if (count * (distance < within_radius)) > 0 else (continue)`

Comment: How can I use a boolean list in between? `list = 5 if [boolean list] else 0`?

Answer (score 71):

Python's `if` can be used as a [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/Booleans.html):

```
>>> 'true' if True else 'false'
'true'
>>> 'true' if False else 'false'
'false'
```

Comment: Just want to add the "true" command-line one-line syntax for the that. I have searched a lot how to do that, but no one answer contains this information:
$ python -c "import sys; var=1; [ sys.stdout.write('POS\n') if var>0 else sys.stdout.write('NEG\n')]"

Answer (score 45):

Only for using as a value:

```
x = 3 if a==2 else 0
```

or

```
return 3 if a==2 else 0
```

Comment: This is not restricted to assignment.  It can be used in any expression.

Answer (score 29):

There is the conditional expression:

```
a if cond else b
```

but this is an expression, not a statement.

In if statements, the `if` (or `elif` or `else`) can be written on the same line as the body of the block if the block is just one like:

```
if something: somefunc()
else: otherfunc()
```

but this is discouraged as a matter of formatting-style.